# I am building a Facebook Tab with a Fan gate (html & PHP). How to avoid SSL or find a free solution ? Do you have some idea?

Tags: facebook

I'm really amazed that facebook is forcing us to pay for that. I just need a tab with a fan gate (html & PHP). Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of free hosts support SSL, including Google App Engine, maybe host your app there?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook offers cloud hosting for applications through Heroku. Here is a guide that will get you up and running:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook